# Anime male and female power grows based on bond

Tags: story-identification, anime

I will try and describe what I remember from the anime.

It starts off following a girl. She is in school. I believe she meets this guy on top of the schools roof. He says they have to pair and duel others for some reason I can't remember why. But as their bond grows so will their power in getting stronger to defeat others.

Then I remember a group of separate couples comes to fight them. One pair being twins whose bond was very strong.

I don't remember any weapons just they all had certain powers.